# Insert Statement error for Access Database

Tags: ms-access, python-3.x, pypyodbc

I'm trying to add data to a database (well MS Access) using python with pypyodbc.
I've tested my insert statement in MS Access as a query and it works. The problem is when I run it inside my programme it brings up the following error:

```
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.')
```

My insert statement looks as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Database (columnAText,columnBText,columnText,columnDTime,columnEText,columnFText,columnGNumber) VALUES ('a','b','c','00:00:17','e','f','100')
```

Please note that the column headings include their type as part of their name as this is a test table.

The programme works as so:

There are more columns than in the insert statement because there is an autoincrement column for ID. This means the columns have to be defined in the insert statement in order to submit data into the correct columns. Therefore if a row has a null entry that column is missed from the insert statement.

I cannot see what is wrong with the insert statement, especially as it works directly in MS Access.

I am using ActivePython33 with pypyodbc, MS Access 2010, on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

`DATABASE` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) in Access SQL so you'll need to enclose it in square brackets:

```sql
INSERT INTO [Database] ...
```